# solve the given set of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got these equations$$2x-2y+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{2014}\tag{1}$$

$$2y-2z+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2014}\tag{2}$$

$$2z-2x+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2014}\tag{3}$$

I added them

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{2014}$$

But I am not able to proceed

Comment: $x=y=z=2014$ is a solution, but one should see if there are more.

Comment: A trivial solution is $x=y=z=2014$.

Comment: can you provide me detailed solution

Answer (score 4):

Adding the three equations, we get $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} = \frac{3}{2014}$$ We can also write the equations in the form $$2zx − 2zy + 1 = \frac{z}{2014} , 2xy − 2xz + 1 = \frac{x}{2014} , 2yz − 2yx + 1 = \frac{y}{2014}$$  Adding these, we also get $2014 \times 3 = x + y + z$. Therefore $$\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}\right)(x + y + z) = \frac{3}{2014} \times (2014 \times 3) = 9$$ Using AM-GM inequality, we can conclude $x = y = z$. Thus $$x = 2014, y = 2014, z = 2014$$   Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@Rohan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/371838/rohan)'s answer needs more explanation, so I will put it here.

For all $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R}$, by the Commutative and Distributive Properties, we have:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}\right)(x + y + z)=\frac{x}{x}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{z}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{y}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}+\frac{z}{y}+\frac{z}{z} \\=3+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{z}+\frac{z}{x}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}$$
Now, expressions like $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$ are the sum of a number and its reciprocal, meaning it is at least $2$. This can be proven with either AM-GM inequality or [with calculus](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-x-+-1-x). This gives us the following:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}\right)(x + y + z) \geq 3+2+2+2=9$$
Now, we want to find when we will have equality, as that is what our given equations imply. We will have equality when and only when $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=2$ and the same can be said for the pairs with $x, z$ and $y, z$. Again, according to calculus/AM-GM, this only happens when $\frac{x}{y}=1$, so we get $x=y$. Applying this to the other pairs gives us $x=y=z$. This is how we know $x=y=z$ is the only solution for these equations.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the three equations, we get,

$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} +  \frac{1}{z} = \frac{3}{2014}$ .........(1)

We can also write the equations in the form-

2zx − 2zy + 1 = $\frac{z}{2014}$

2xy − 2xz + 1 = $\frac{x}{2014}$

2yz − 2yx + 1 = $\frac{y}{2014}$

Adding these, we also get

3 * 2014 = (x + y + z). ........(2)

On multiplying equation (1) and (2),

$(\frac{1}{x} +  \frac{1}{y} +  \frac{1}{z}) (x + y + z) = \frac{3}{2014} × (2014 × 3) = 9$

Using AM-GM inequality, we therefore obtain,

$9 = (\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z})(x + y + z) ≥ 9 $

Hence equality holds in AM-GM inequality and we conclude x = y = z.

Thus $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2014}$ which gives x = 2014.

We conclude x = 2014, y = 2014, z = 2014.